# Understanding Python's struct pack/unpack functions

Tags: struct, python-3.6

I am working on project which includes usage of `struct` module and its `pack/unpack` functions with python3.6

I have referred to many articles like [this one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/struct-module-python/) and have got the basic idea but I am not able to understand it for my use case.

For ex:

```
var = struct.pack('i',1) 
print(var)
```

It gives output `b'\x01\x00\x00\x00'` which I can understand because we have mentioned int as  format and thus output is of 4 bytes.

Now another example:

```
var = struct.pack('i', 1156888062)
```

Now in this case why is the output `b'\xfe\xb5\xf4D'`. Can anyone please explain this.

Also when I unpack it

```
print(struct.unpack('f', var))
```

How come the output is `(1957.687255859375,)`

Comment: Why are you packing it as an integer and unpacking a float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> struct.pack('i', 1156888062)
b'\xfe\xb5\xf4D'
```

This is still four bytes, it's just that one of those bytes is a printable ASCII character `D` so it's displaying as that instead of as `\x44`. It's only a different representation. Proof:

```
>>> len(b'\xfe\xb5\xf4D')
4
>>> b'\x44'
b'D'
```

For the last bit, you need to `unpack` using the same format specifier you packed as. You're asking to interpret those same four bytes as a float, so obviously it'll give you a different result. Change it to `'i'` and it'll work as expected:

```
>>> struct.unpack('f', var)
(1957.687255859375,)
>>> struct.unpack('i', var)
(1156888062,)
```

Comment: I want the result in float thats why `f` is used.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I want the result in float"? Are you looking for `1156880862.0`? Because the same four bytes interpreted as `int` or `float` will mean vastly different things.